SolutionFall.com breaking SO TOS by reusing user content without attribution - does using AI to reword SO content void the need for attribution?
Today, I asked this question on Stack Overflow. Later, while continuing to research possible solutions, I came across a suspiciously similar question on "solutionfall.com" (Wayback Machine). I did not make this post on Solution Fall.
The similarity in the content of the two posts, and the coincidence in timing, strongly suggests to me that Solution Fall had scraped SO for this question, had an AI reword it, and then posted it on their website - then had AI write a completely nonsensical and unhelpful response which is not present on SO.
Looking more on the Solution Fall site, it seems that they've done this with a lot of other posts too. The footer of the site may also suggest that they're claiming that the content on their site is their own copyrighted material (though it may also be referring to something else about the site).
Is this a violation of SO's TOS and the CC BY-SAA 4.0 license under which our questions and answers are held? Is there anything that can or should be done about this?
I have reported the site to SO. However, discussion may remain to be had on whether using AI to reword SO content removes the need for attribution and lets Solution Fall hold copyright over the altered content on their own site.

Only a copyright holder can pursue this. I.e. you if you think your copyright/licence has been violated.

@AbdulAzizBarkat somewhat. I sent in a report (thanks for the information), but I think a discussion remains to be had on whether using AI to re-word SO content removes the need for attribution is considered new content to which solutionfall can hold copyright.

@JoshBrunton "I sent in a report" uhh the answer there actually mentions certain conditions when you should report, this case doesn't match any of those so you shouldn't have actually reported that to the company. You'll have to get your own legal help if you want to pursue this as the author.

"I think a discussion remains to be had on whether using AI to re-word SO content removes the need for attribution" IMO that is very much into legal territory and I feel Meta Stack Overflow isn't a suitable place for that discussion, you can try posting on [law.se] it might be suitable there (Read their help center first!)
